# Show that not every number of the form $N = (p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_n) + 1$ is prime, where $p_1, p_2, p_3,...,p_n$ is the list of all prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

How would you show that not every number of the form $N = (p_1  p_2 p_3 \cdots p_n) + 1$ is prime,
where $p_1, p_2, p_3,...,p_n$ is the list of all prime numbers?

I have tried several proof techniques including the proof of infinitely many primes but to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no exhaustive, yet finite list of prime numbers. Do you mean $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ are the first $n$ prime numbers? If so, I would recommend searching for a counterexample.

Comment: See [Euclid's  proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid's_proof)

Comment: @user754697, $p_1$,...,$p_n$ is the list of all prime numbers.

Comment: @DYBnor The point is that there are infinitely many primes. So either $p_1\times p_2\times \ldots \times p_n=2\times3\times\ldots$ is infinite or it contains a finite subset of the primes (e.g., the first ones).

Answer (score 5):

You could just do it by counterexample. The [Euclid numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number) are the numbers of the form $p_n\#+1$, where $p\#$ denotes the "primorial" (the product of the primes less than or equal to $p$). These are exactly what you desire in form: $p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime in this context.

The first composite Euclid number is the sixth one:

$$p_6\# +1 = 13\# + 1 = 30031 = 59 \times 509$$

Comment: @ Evee Trainer, I am a bit confused. How can you use counterexample when the statement has got 'not' in it.? In am thinking in this case $p_6$# + 1 confirms the statement.

Comment: @DYBnor It's a counterexample to the claim that *all* numbers of the form $p_n\#+1$ are prime. So it's an example that proves your claim. It just depends on which angle you look at the problem. Mostly, you'd phrase this type of conjecture as "proposition X is true for all $n$".